# Can anyone explain how to solve this kind of questions?

Tags: congruence-relations

Here's the question:

Find an appropriate solution for x.

≡ 2 ( 3)

≡ 2 ( 5)

≡ 5 ( 7)

≡ 7 ( 8)

I saw some examples like this question...but I still don't know what to do.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @whiteianmotion Usually called [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As 
$$
x \equiv 2 \ (\mod 3),
$$
so there exists an integer $n_1$ such that 
$$
x = 3n_1 + 2. \tag{1}
$$
Then
$$
x \equiv 2 \ ( \mod 5)
$$
becomes 
$$
3n_1 + 2 \equiv 2 \ ( \mod 5),
$$
which implies
$$
3n_1 \equiv 0 \ ( \mod 5),
$$
and since $\gcd(3, 5) = 1$, we obtain
$$
n_1 \equiv 0 \ ( \mod 5),
$$
and thus there exists an integer $n_2$ such that
$$
n_1 = 5n_2,
$$
and then (1) gives 
$$
x = 3n_1 = 3 \left( 5 n_2 \right) = 15 n_2. \tag{2}
$$
Then 
$$
x \equiv 5 \ (\mod 7)
$$
becomes
$$
15 n_2 \equiv 5 \ ( \mod 7),
$$
and since $\gcd( 5, 7) = 1$, we obtain
$$
3n_2 \equiv 1 \ ( \mod 7),
$$
and since $$ 1 \equiv 15 \ ( \mod 7), $$
we obtain
$$
3n_2 \equiv 15 \ ( \mod 7),
$$
and since $\gcd( 3, 7) = 1$, we have 
$$
n_2 \equiv 5 \ ( \mod 7),
$$
and thus there exists an integer $n_3$ such that
$$
n_2 = 7n_3 + 5,
$$
and then (2) gives 
$$
x = 15 n_2 = 15 \left( 7 n_3 + 5 \right) = 105 n_3 + 75. \tag{3}
$$
Then 
$$
x \equiv 7 \ (\mod 8)
$$
becomes
$$
105 n_3 + 75 \equiv 7 \ (\mod 8),
$$
and since $7 \equiv 15 \ ( \mod 8)$, we have 
$$
105 n_3 + 75 \equiv 15 \ ( \mod 8),
$$
which implies
$$ 105 n_3 \equiv -60 \ ( \mod 8), $$
and since $\gcd( 15, 8) = 1$, we obtain
$$
7n_3 \equiv -4 \ (\mod 8),
$$
and since $-4 \equiv 4 \ ( \mod 8)$, we obtain
$$
7 n_3 \equiv 4 \ ( \mod 8),
$$
and since $4 \equiv 28\  ( \mod 8)$, we can write
$$
7 n_3 \equiv 28 \ ( \mod 8),
$$
and since $\gcd(7, 8) = 1$, therefore we get
$$
n_3 \equiv 4 \ ( \mod 8),
$$
and so there exists an integer $n_4$ such that
$$
n_3 = 8n_4 + 4,
$$
and then (3) gives
$$
x = 105 n_3 + 75 = 105 \left( 8n_4 + 4 \right) + 75 = 840n_4 + 495,
$$
which implies that
$$
x \equiv 495 \ ( \mod 840).
$$

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! You explained pretty well and in detail! I appreciate your taking the time to write.

Comment: @YasamanFarhangi please do check to see to it that I've not made any errors in my calculation.